# entering a phrase to scanf("%c", &ch)... (%c for sequence, not for single symbol)

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I'm going through lessons at S.Prata book: 'C Primer Plus'. Chapter 6, control question #8:

```
// Given the input Go west, young man!, what would each of the following
// programs produce for output? (The ! follows the space character in the
// ASCII sequence.)

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char ch;
  scanf("%c", &ch);
  while (ch != 'g') {
    printf("%c", ch);
    scanf("%c", &ch);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The thing is... as far as I know `%c` in `scanf` should be used for a single character, not for a phrase like 'Go west, young man!'. Why this program read all the line and stores all of it (except last word), not only first character? Does it automatically store stuff in `scanf` as an array?

I thought it will print just 'G'... But it actually prints 'Go west, youn'. Why? It's not `%s`, but `%c`.

I suppose it could be because `%c` stores all input to 'char'.. but in specifications it said that it stores only single character, not several ones.

Comment: I recommend that you learn how to use a *debugger*. With it you can step through the code, statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values. If you do that then you can see exactly what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is also required for solving complex problems, and really something you need to know if you're anywhere near serious about programming.

Comment: Yep, I'm using debugger, thanks. The question was about storing long phrase in %c buffer (single character spot), not about reading from buffer

Comment: If you step through the code in a debugger, you will see that you're not storing any "long phrase" anywhere, only the single characters one by one.

Comment: I suppose that book has a chapter about loop constructs, using `for`, `while` and `do ... while`. It seems that you haven't grasped the concept of looping yet, so I recommend reading the chapter again.

Comment: Because `G` and `g` are different characters. One is uppercase, and one is lowercase.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I suppose I mixed up term 'debugger' and function which I use. I've got 'Borland C++Builder 6' and there is 'Step Over' function which doing program by steps (1 string at one time). Does it called debugger or it's different thing?

Comment: @IanAbbott I've grasped it.. but I didn't grasped how scanf works :) Thanks to Youssef13 now I undestand it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character `ch` will never store a whole string, it only stores one character. The output you're getting is **NOT** given by a single `printf` execution, it's by multiple executions of `printf`s (The loop enters multiple times). You can confirm that by changing the code to:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char ch;
  scanf("%c", &ch);
  while (ch != 'g')
  {
    printf("PRINTING: %c\n", ch);
    scanf("%c", &ch);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now, let's see why the loop enters multiple times.

You entered many characters in the scanf outside the loop, then in the loop you expect it to print the first character, which is totally correct. BUT, you think it will wait for the user input again, which is **not** correct. In the first `scanf`, when you entered multiple characters, it just read the first one. But there is somehow a hidden cursor in the stdin (standard input) that keeps track of what has been read. When you entered "Go west, young man!", the `G` is stored in ch and the cursor is put before the `o`. When you next call `scanf`, it will look at the cursor position and finds an `o`, so it won't wait for user input and just reads it. etc.

To summarize, I suspect your problem is that you misunderstand how scanf works. You think that it will always wait for user input whenever called. That is not the case, it may read from the previous input.

If you want the next `scanf`s to ignore the long first input, you should actually read it (or seek the stdin which will work in Windows but not Linux). Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char ch;
  scanf("%c", &ch);
  while (getchar() != '\n'); // Get to the end of the stdin.
  // The previous line can be replaced with fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); but it will work under Windows only.

  while (ch != 'g')
  {
    printf("PRINTING: %c\n", ch);
    scanf("%c", &ch);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dear Youssef13! Thank you very much for a great explanation!

Comment: I've wrote an article, where I've included your explanation: http://skobki.com/yazyk-c-zagadochnyj-scanf-vvoditsya-neskolko-simvolov-s-c-glava-6/ :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a loop, which has the `scanf()` in it's body

```
while ( ch != 'g' )
```

so, it keeps on reading the inputs present in the buffer, until it finds a `'g'`.

So, for the input

```
  'Go west, young man!'.
                ^---------------- here is the 'g'
```

It'll keep on reading the characters one by one, in each iteration till it reads the `'g'` and encounters the exit criteria for the loop.

Comment: yep, it's understandable. the question was - why scanf() store to buffer whole phrase  'Go west, young man!', not only 'G'. As it's scanf("%c", &ch), not a scanf("%s", &ch);

Comment: @igroglaz Given `ch` is a `char`, `scanf("%s", &ch);` is wrong. That said, with `%s`, the input is matched and stored at one go, there's no looping needed. However, in this case, because of the loop, it keeps on reading from the input buffer one after another.

Comment: In other words, each call to `scanf("%c", &ch);` reads, matches ad stores one character at a time. Combined that with the loop, it reads multiple..

Comment: @igroglaz replace the while with if then you will get your expected output.since while checks for "g" in the string and execute till "g".

Comment: guys, thanks, BUT I still didn't got an answer. I suppose it's my bad English, so it's hard to understand me. 

Again: I've read in the book that %c - is for single character. So when this program has scanf("%c", &ch); (at beginning! string #4) - it should store only 1st symbol of phrase, as it's %c, not %s, isn't it? Why ' scanf("%c", &ch)' at string #4 stores this long phrase, instead of just storing 'G'?

Other part of program is very simple and undertandable. The question is about actually initial storing of this phrase, which become store at a 'string', while scanf got a %c

Comment: @igroglaz You read one character and you print one character, 14 times. Try to replace your `printf()` by `printf("Read character: '%c'\n", ch);`, maybe it's more clear then what happens.

Comment: @igroglaz Did you notice the other call to `scanf` _inside_ the loop?

Answer (score 1):

The program simply reads all characters *one by one* of the input.

So for an input such as

```
Go west, young man!
```

then the first call to `scanf` reads the single character `'G'`. Then in the loop you print that single `'G'`, followed by reading the single character `'o'`. Then in the next iteration of the loop you print the single character `'o'` (that you read in the previous iteration) and then read the space `' '`. And so on.

Also note that `'G'` is not equal to `'g'`. Character comparison is case-sensitive.

Comment: yep, it's understandable. the question was - why scanf() store to buffer whole phrase 'Go west, young man!', not only 'G'. As it's scanf("%c", &ch), not a scanf("%s", &ch);

Comment: @igroglaz And I told you: It doesn't read the "whole phrase", it read one character at a time.

Comment: The question is about storing long phrase in %c buffer (single character spot), not about reading from buffer

Comment: @igroglaz But as I said in another comment, your program doesn't store any "long phrase" anywhere, all you store is a *single character* in the `ch` variable. And since you have a loop which runs over and over and over again, you will read a single character over and over and over again.

Comment: yep, I understood it from beginning :) There was a problem with my mistundestanding how C buffer stores stuff and how scanf takes it from there 8)